# How to extract a function with its args ? Lua Code

Tags: design-patterns, lua, macros, latex

I was trying to write some Lua code to search list all occurrences of a macro I made in my .tex file and to put them at the end of my file. 
So I'd like to find all the occurrences of `"\Citation{text1}{text2}{text2}"` in a string and to return a list containing all the occurrences with the same format.
I have :

```
output = {}
for elt in string.gmatch(str,"\\Citation(%b{}%b{}%b{})") do 
    output[#output + 1] = elt
end
```

But the issue is that it only returns `text1text2text3` concatenated and not `"\Citation{text1}{text2}{text2}"`. I'm not very familiar with Lua.
If someone could help me

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

Change your pattern to capture the whole thing: `"(\\Citation%b{}%b{}%b{})"`.